# multithreading - increment integer in one thread and decrease in another thread

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, locking, multicore

In a multi-threaded program where 2 threads -
thread 1 - will run a loop that increases an integer variable 1000 times and then exits
thread 2 - will run a loop that decreases an integer variable 1000 times and then exits

Both threads wait on a semaphore and start roughly at the same time and are scheduled to run on different cores approximately same time.

After both the threads exit, will the value of the integer variable will be zero?
Note: no locking(mutex etc..) is used

Let us assume linux and x86 architecture and multi-core hardware.

What happens for above if the same integer is declared as volatile (C++) ?

Comment: The answer is no, the value will not necessarily be zero, unless you use an atomic integer.

Comment: No locking - does it mean that increment/decrement operations aren't atomic? If so final zero value is not guaranteed.

Comment: @Rost..the operations are plain integer increment/decrements lets says ++i and --i

Comment: @Medicine This means result is not guaranteed to be zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If more than one thread modifies the same memory location at the same time the program has a data race and the effects are undefined. The result can be pretty much anything, assuming you get a result at all. For simple variables like integer types, atomics will eliminate the data race and provide proper synchronization. Use `atomic_int` (also known as `atomic<int>`).

Answer (score 5):

Volatile or not, you cannot expect any specific output (except in the range [-1000,1000]) -- even a single concurrent write might spoil the outcome of an increment/decrement (which is not atomic even at the CPU level).

Comment: "Both threads wait on a semaphore and start at the same time ... " This is not possible, only one thread will be started in a given time and other thread will be waiting on semaphore.  In your case; If Thread1 starts running first then It will increment the value by 1000 times say from 0 to 1000 and then Thread2 starting running which decrement the value by 1000 times so the value will be 0. Consider, if Thread 2 starts first then the value will become -1000 and then at the end of Thread1 the value will be 0.

Comment: If you allow only one of them to run at the particular time, then of course the output will be 0. But if they run concurrently, my answer applies.

Comment: @Viswesn there are 2 cores on the machine and the semaphores value is raised to 2 by an external process causing both the threads' sem_wait to succeed...so both the threads will approximately scheduled around same time....if 1000 iterations are too small, lets say there is a million iterations instead for each thread to increment and  decrement correspondingly

Comment: @Medicine Thanks for specifying it is counting semaphore.

Answer (score 3):

Increment and decrement require three operations: fetch the value from memory, modify it, and write it back to memory. On most platforms, there's no guarantee that these three operations are all performed atomically, unless you specifically request it using the C++11 atomic types, compiler-specific (or assembly) atomic intrinsics, or a lock.

`volatile` has nothing to do with thread synchronisation; it just ensures that the memory accesses actually happen and are sequenced correctly relative to other side effects in the same thread.

Answer (score 2):

you will need to use proper atomics, and potentially full memory barriers.

`volatile` will do nothing for you in this case (well enough that you could use).

Answer (score 2):

Integer read/writes may or may not be atomic. So the answer is no, the result isn't necessarily 0.